# How to set the name of a tabPage progragmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a method that creates a series of tabPages, although it only defines the "text" value (title) of them, how can I set the "name" of the tab pages as well?

```
foreach (string s in hostnames)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(s);
    hostView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);

    string title = s;
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```

Comment: Taking your previous questions into account, `TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title) { Name = title };` would do the trick.

Comment: Just see the Initializecomponent() method of the winforms class. Youll get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) Property for setting the name:

```
foreach (string s in hostnames)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(s);
    hostView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);

    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(s);
    myTabPage.Name = "Name you want to set";
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```